# Connecting to RDS MySql from Lambda using IAM Roles is timing out

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I currently have a lambda function set up to generate a token based on its IAM policy.  I'm successfully generating a Token, but when I attempt to use it to connect to RDS MySql (5.7.xx), it just times out.

IAM Policy (which is associated with the role tied to the lambda function)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds-db:connect"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:<account-id>:dbuser:<db-resource-id>/lambda"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

User created in the DB:

```
create user 'lambda' identified with AWSAuthenticationPlugin as 'RDS';
grant all privileges on cbr.* to 'lambda'@'%';
flush privileges;
```

Here are the code snippets for what I've attempted to do so far:

```
private String generateAuthToken() {
    RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator generator = RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator.builder()
        .credentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
    .region(region)
    .build();

    String authToken = generator.getAuthToken(
    GetIamAuthTokenRequest.builder()
        .hostname(hostName)
        .port(Integer.parseInt(port))
        .userName(username)
        .build());

    return authToken;
}
```

```
public String test() throws SQLException {
    String currentTime = "Not Set";
    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + hostName + ":" + port;
    String token = generateAuthToken();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, generateAuthToken());

    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT NOW()");

    if (rs.next()) {
        currentTime = rs.getString(1);
    }

    return currentTime;
}
```

I'm sure I'm just missing something

Comment: "it" just times out?  What specifically times out?  The connection or the entire Lambda invocation?  This issue will be unrelated to the fact that you are using IAM auth.

Answer (score 0):

If you have timeout in most cases it means that you do not have an access to your service. 
Please check your security group that you assigned to mysql. 
For testing purposes allow all traffic inbound.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check if Lambda has correct network settings. Especially if you're using framework like Chalice which used to clear network setting during deploy.